# What is Bundle, View, Context?

Tags: android

Guys I have watched tutorial on YouTube about android it has 200 videos but didn't explain what is Bundle, View and Context.

**1st question** what is Bundle?

**2nd question** what is bundle inside onCreate method **where that come from**? what inside that bundle?

**3nd question** what is Context? what I found is that Activity extends Context, so is it right to say that Context is the activity itself? or the Context of that activity?

**4th question** what is View? what I found is that TextView extends View and other widgets like Button EditText extend TextView so it means they also extends View.
I also found that the syntax of Button, EditText and other widgets  is this...

```
TextView(Context);
Button(Context);
EditText(Context);
```

so my assumption here is that
 **"Context = Activity = Screen" and that "View = Button = TextView = EditText"**

so in this example

```
public Example extends Activity{

    onCreate(){
        Button buttonObj = new Button(this):
    }
}
```

`Button buttonObj = new Button(this);` 
**"this keyword"** here is refering to the Example class which extends Activity. Is this code here basically says **"put this Button which is View inside the Context which is Activity which is the Screen"**?
If I am right then why Activity passed inside Button? because it makes sense if button is passed inside Activity.

**5th question** what happen here?

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //code here

    }
});
```

What is new View.onclickListener() ?? is this a static method that returns an object who implements onClickListener??

**Can you also suggest good books in learning android?**

Comment: Start from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: can I download that doc?

Comment: Good books 'Pro Android 4', 'Busy Coder's Guide to Android Developmnent'. Regarding 'what is View', 'what is Context' etc those questions are of little practical use (my personal opinion that is though)

Comment: First step to learn android apps. http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Bundle ~  a Bundle is a collection of data.  When an Activity starts (via onCreate), the Android OS (or you!) can pass off some extra data to this activity via this bundle.  Do you know what a HashMap is?  A bundle is a glorified hashmap in that supports multiple different types.

OnCreate Bundle ~ This bundle comes from Android.  Honestly, don't worry about it too much.  If you want to start one activity from another, you use an intent (do you know this yet?).  As such, you can "bundle" data into the intent (using the `setExtra` methods).  This data from the intent will be included in this onCreate bundle, and you can access it through there.

Context ~ your running application and anything associated with it.  When you run your application, everything associated with your application is referenced by this context.  All of you activities, views, resources, EVERYTHING is associated with the context.  Think of it as the word defines:  It is the context of your application.  Every application has a unique context.

View ~  A view is anything that can be drawn on screen.

Comment: Yes I know how to pass bundle via intent, Im just curious about bundle that passes in the onCreate(). Why Context is passed inside the View not the View inside the Context?

Comment: The bundle in onCreate contains the data from your intent.  A view, by itself, has no reference to where it exists.  It is just "something that can be drawn".  As such, you have to associate any new view with your application's unique context.

Comment: so Button buttonObj = new Button(this); associates view with the context? not put context inside view?

Comment: By `new Button(this)` you are giving the `Button` a reference to the `Context`.  This will create an association from the view to the context.  This will allow a view to know which context it is a part of.

Answer (score 1):

OnCreate():
The entire lifetime of an activity happens between the first call
to onCreate() through to a single final call to onDestroy().
An activity does all its initial setup of "global" state in
onCreate(), and releases all remaining resources in
onDestroy(). For example, if it has a thread running in the
background to download data from the network, it may create
that thread in onCreate() and then stop the thread in
onDestroy().
OnCreate method is called when the activity is first
created. This is where you
should do all of your normal
static set up — create views,
bind data to lists, and so on.
This method is passed a Bundle
object containing the activity's
previous state, if that state was
captured.

Views:
The visual content of the window is provided by a hierarchy of views — objects derived from the base View class.
Each view controls a particular rectangular space within the window. Parent views contain and organize the layout of their children. Leaf views (those at the bottom of the hierarchy) draw in the rectangles they control and respond to user actions directed at that space. Thus, views are where the activity's interaction with the user takes place.
For example, a view might display a small image and initiate an action when the user taps that image. Android has a number of ready-made views(Widgets) that you can use — including buttons, text fields, scroll bars, menu items,check boxes, and more.

Comment: what about bundle that passed in that oncreate() where did that comefrom?

Comment: `onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)` If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`. Go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and you will get all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look at some text based tutorials rather than video as it will be easier to look at things and reread when you are confused.

I'll get started to help you with figuring out what these terms means.

Bundle - not super important for you to understand.  When an activity is called, you can add things to your bundle to be sent to the next activity so that the new activity has the information you want.

Context - each activity has its own context and its important to have a basic understanding of it.  Your first applications will have one activity (or class) from which everything is done.  In this case you only have to worry about the "this" context which means the current active activity.  But if you use an application with multiple activities, some may be active and others not.  The context tells your app which of the activities is requesting an action, such as showing text or an image on the screen.

Views are your basic UI elements.  They can be simple like TextViews (just shows text), Buttons, or more complex like a layout which organizes the other views.

For your example :

```
public Example extends Activity{
     onCreate(){
          Button buttonObj = new Button(this):
          }
```

}
Example is the name of your class which uses the Activity resources.
When the activity "Example" is started it calls the onCreate method first.
It then creates a button object that you can "attach" to a physical button found in your layout file.

The setOnClickListener method is used to ready your activity for a button click.  The code that goes into the onClick section is what will happen if the user clicks the button.

If you want to get into android programming, you really should first read the FAQ on this site.  You should only be posting answerable questions not asking for opinions such as what's a good book.  Hundreds of people have already asked that question and if you can't do a simple google search, you might want to wait on learning to program.

But I"m nice so here are some online tutorials that will get you started and explain some of the things you are confused about:

http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102065/Android-A-beginner-s-guide

Comment: I know what setOnClickListener do. Please look at my question about setOncClickListener.

Comment: In that block of code it is setting the onClickListener for a button named "add".  NOthing actually happens though because there is no code in the onClick section.